# Request body is empty in Express router middleware

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

This is my simple nodejs app using express:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const user = require('./routes/user').user;
const browser = require('./routes/browser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// CORS middleware
const allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    next();
}

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(allowCrossDomain);

app.use('/', user);
app.use('/', browser);

const port = process.env.PORT || 4001;

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + port)
});
```

Route handler "browser", where I added middleware:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.use(function (req, res, next) { 
    console.log(req.body);
    next();
});

router.post('/get-content', (req, res) => { 

});
```

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m72B1.png)

Here I got strange behaviour with middleware. I want to get request body data, but in console I see empty object instead expected body with content. After calling next() middleware fires second time and finally I am getting request body. Help me understand middleware behaviour in my case.

Comment: Looks like the first request is the [CORS preflight request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request).

Comment: Which program are you using to send the POST request?

Comment: @David Vicente POST request sent by frontend app with Axios

Comment: @robertklep thanks much, you've helped me a lot. I must handle Preflight request by express app middleware.

Answer (score 2):

It`s can be help. Install cors package, and give it in express.use.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Comment: Thanks much. Using this package solving my problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Middleware to support CORS pre-flight requests

```
const allowCrossDomain = function(req, res, next) { 
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');

    //intercepts OPTIONS method
    if ('OPTIONS' === req.method) {
        res.sendStatus(200);
      } else {
        next();
      }
}
```